# How to handle stuck updates?

Tags: software-update

I've got a (current other than this latest update - *edit* macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Update) OS X which has stopped updating.  It lists the update, goes through the install, says to reboot.  However, after rebooting the same update is in the list.  Looking at the history it has "installed" probably a dozen times now...  Obviously it's not working, but whatever is failing is happening silently.  No error messages.  Looking for debugging suggestions if not outright solutions such as "yeah that latest update is just bad".  :-)

Comment: You could try to relaunch the App Store with holding the left Shift. The App Store will re-evaluate the cache which could solve your problem

Comment: Left shift App Store did not work, same problem  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded the .DMG and installed in safe mode (hold down shift key during boot until login appears).  Never could determine why it was failing in normal mode.

Comment: You have probably installed an extension or a browser or a firewall application which interfer with connections that are done during the MacOS X installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Try the combo updater instead - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1970 for a direct download link which you run like any app.

You can always Google for "10.x.y combo update" & it will be the top hit.
It will apply all updates since 10.x.0 without needing any intermediate updates & is often used to fix odd update glitches.

Failing that, then try reinstalling the OS from Recovery.
This will not affect existing apps, docs etc - though of course, as with any operation like this having a current backup is always wise.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  Same exact issue.  Appears to install, but then after logging in it is not installed.

Comment: try relaying the OS from Recovery - added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Search for the official 10.13.6 combo update](http://lmgtfy.com/?s=d&q=MacOS%20X%2010.13.6%20combo%20update) .

This will most probably work because your problem is coming from a previous corrupted download which is in your updates download cache and isn't verified before run. Since this combo update was probably not yet downloaded, it will be clean.

To improve your chances to avoid the same problem, avoid to make system downloads when you are connected through Wi-Fi within an area where it might get shut down for any usual reason.

Comment: Same results as running it from the App Store unfortunately :-(  What kind of support/troubleshooting options are there?